# Python/Selenium: Automate clicking button on a website

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need some help here:

I have a code, written on Python/Selenium that perform some actions, basic actions, get names in a website. That works perfeclty fine.

The aim:

The thing is... I would like to automate the action for the whole page, this includes all pages defined on the site.

These actions need to be performed in each page out of *100* pages (within same website)
I would like, using Pyhton/Selenium, automate the change of the pages, do the same on *Page 2, Page 3* and so on.

Screenshot, "Inspect" website:
[image: Screenshot, "Inspect" website:]

This is the part of the HTML were the buttons for pages are defined:

```
        <div id="ember450" class="ember-view   ">
            
    <div id="ember472" class="artdeco-pagination artdeco-pagination--has-controls ember-view pv5 ph2">  <button disabled="" aria-label="Anterior" id="ember473" class="artdeco-pagination__button artdeco-pagination__button--previous artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--disabled ember-view" type="button">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-left-icon" class="artdeco-button__icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="mercado-match" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M11 1L6.39 8 11 15H8.61L4 8l4.61-7z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>

<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Anterior
</span></button>

  <ul class="artdeco-pagination__pages artdeco-pagination__pages--number">
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="1" id="ember474" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number active selected ember-view">  <button aria-current="true" aria-label="Página 1" type="button">
    <span>1</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="2" id="ember475" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 2" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-476="476">
    <span>2</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="3" id="ember477" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 3" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-478="478">
    <span>3</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="4" id="ember479" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 4" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-480="480">
    <span>4</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="5" id="ember481" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 5" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-482="482">
    <span>5</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="6" id="ember483" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 6" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-484="484">
    <span>6</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="7" id="ember485" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 7" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-486="486">
    <span>7</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="8" id="ember487" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 8" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-488="488">
    <span>8</span>
  </button>

</li>
        <li id="ember489" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view"><button aria-label="Página 9" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-490="490">
  <span>…</span>
</button>
</li>
        <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="100" id="ember491" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  <button aria-label="Página 100" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-492="492">
    <span>100</span>
  </button>

</li>
  </ul>
    <div class="artdeco-pagination__page-state">
      Página 1 de 100
    </div>

  <button aria-label="Siguiente" id="ember493" class="artdeco-pagination__button artdeco-pagination__button--next artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--icon-right artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view" type="button">  <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-right-icon" class="artdeco-button__icon" size="small"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="mercado-match" data-supported-dps="16x16" fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" focusable="false">
  <path d="M5 15l4.61-7L5 1h2.39L12 8l-4.61 7z"></path>
</svg></li-icon>

<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Siguiente
</span></button>
</div>
  
        </div>
  

      </div>
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create an instance of the Chrome WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

page_number = 2
driver.get("https://www.example.com/search/pagina=1")

while page_number < 100:
    # Start performing actions on the current page
    # ...

    next_page_button_xpath = f'//button[@aria-label="Página {page_number}"]'
    next_page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, next_page_button_xpath)
    next_page_button.click()

    page_number += 1

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()
```

But, I am getting the following exception:

> *no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@aria-label="Página 2"]"} hen the
> html that contains the button to click on the page is 
> 2*

I have already doublechecked the HTML source code, several times... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error states `Page 2` but you use `Página {page_number}`, so which one is it? Can you post the actual code and the actual error, please?

Comment: Hey,  it is "Página 2" .. I have run the code into to versions of the website. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML mark-up shared by you in the question, below is the desired element:

```
<button aria-label="Página 2" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-476="476" class="">
    <span>2</span>
</button>
```

Your XPath expression as per the ERROR is:

```
//button[@aria-label="Page 2"]
```

Change it to:

```
//button[@aria-label="Página 2"]
```

### UPDATE:

 Since you updated your question above solution can be ruled out, try to apply `waits`, see below code for reference:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Página 2']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks. Have you missed "from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By" right?

Comment: Yes I did. Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML:

```
    <li data-test-pagination-page-btn="2" id="ember475" class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ember-view">  
        <button aria-label="Página 2" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-476="476">
            <span>2</span>
    </button>
</li>
```

The element is an [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  page_number = 2
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Página {page_number}']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  page_number = 2
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//button[@aria-label='Página {page_number}']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```